# Image Classification using keras predict same output for different classes

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have problem with my image classification model using keras.
This is the code which have binary class.

tried to set the number of images in datasets as equal.

this is a code for Keras model

```
train_data_dir = 'path'
validation_data_dir = 'path'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)


model.load_weights('second_try.h5')
```

and the model saved well.
so I run the test code

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# dimensions of our images
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('modelpath')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#predicting multiple images at once
img = image.load_img('imgpath', target_size=(img_width, img_height))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

y = image.img_to_array(img)
y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x, y])
classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
```

and both images from different classes are printed as 1.
Why does this happening?

Comment: There might be problem with your model, it might not good enough to predict correct  result.

Comment: are you sure the first test data belonged to class 0?

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving the model or model weights after your training, rather than doing `load_weights` after `fit()`. So, 2 ways to do this

1. After `model.fit()`, do `model.save_weights('second_try.hdf5')` which only saves weights. To load the weights, you should first compile your model, and then call load_weights on the model as `model.load_weights('second_try.hdf5')`
2. After `model.fit()`, do `model.save('model.hdf5')` which saves the weights and the model structure to a single HDF5 file. Then you can use that HDF5 file with `load()` to reconstruct the whole model, including weights. 
   `model = load_model('model.hdf5')`

Also, do check if your test data is being prepared correctly. As your training loop uses a generator to prepare the data, you should use a similar generator for preparing the test data as well.

Comment: thx for your answer. my original code use model.save_weights() but I uploaded the other code which is mixed up with testcode. I don't have problem with saving the model. And when I run the training code,"Found nn images belonging to 2 classes." message comes up. So I think I have right directory in order. Maybe it is because the dataset is too shallow despite of using train generator? but still don't know why classes[0] is 1.. what do you meant  "test data belonged to class 0?"

Comment: You should preprocess the test data in the same way as the training data. I am not sure if you are doing so. Use a similar generator. I don't know what your `predict_classes` function is, but maybe use a `predict_generator` in there.

Comment: It sounds strange that you ask '"doesn't classes[0] should be 0?". the `predict` function gives as output an array of predictions , length equal to your input size i.e. number of test images. So, the first element means prediction for the first test image. If that belongs to your class 0, then yes, it should be 0. Otherwise, not.

Comment: so add   /////


 test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')


//////
inside test file?

Comment: Yes, and then use the `predict_generator`.